# Export query results to excel sheet

Tags: sql

I am using SQLdeveloper to write a query. My requirement is  after fetching the query result the data must be saved in an excel sheet. Please let me know what will be the query to perform this. I do not want to copy the query result to excel manually.

Thanks,
Shubha

Answer (score 0):

For exporting I suggest you to check this guide: https://www.accelebrate.com/library/tutorials/ssis-2008